# c# class update next value based on previous

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a class bound to gridview

```
public class marks
{
 public int ObtainedMarks{get;set;}
 public string Grades{get;set;}
 public string Remarks{get;set;}
}
```

what i want to do is:

```
using(var db=new dbcontext())
{
 var query=db.Grading.where(x=>x.from <=Obtained marks && x.to >= ObtainedMarks).FirstorDefault();
 Grades=query.Grades;
 Remarks=query.Comments;
}
```

how to do this in marks class `{get{}set{}}` where in gridview when i change obtained marks my grades and remarks automatically change regarding to that Obtained marks.

Comment: Not sure what you would like to achieve. Reloading `Grades` and `Remarks` when `ObtainedMarks` changed from UI? What UI environment are you using? `GridView` could be WebForms, WPF but you tagged `DataGridView` which is WinForms...

Comment: using Winfroms,problem solved its working fine..

Answer (score 0):

what i did is which worked out for me:

```
private int obtainedmarks { get; set; }
 public int ObtainedMarks 
 {
      get{return obtainedmarks; } 
      set { this.obtainedmarks = value;
            var que = context.GradingFormulaes.Where(x => x.To >= Percentage && x.From <= Percentage).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                    if(que != null)
                    {
                        this.Remarks = que.Comments;
                        this.Grades = que.Grade;
                    }
```